# Double integral to a single integral?

Tags: integration

Let $P(t)$ is a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $t$ is its variable. Give that $P(t_1+t_2)=P(t_1)+P(t_2)$.

$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty C P(t_1)P(t_2) dt_1 dt_2=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty C P(t_1+t_2) dt_1 dt_2 $

where $C\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector.

My question is is there anyway I can write $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty C P(t_1+t_2) dt_1 dt_2 $ as a single integral?

Comment: Do you know that the double integral converges?

Comment: @JimmyK4542, Hi, thank you for your comment. Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore convergence issues, we can substitute $x = t_1+t_2$, $y = t_1-t_2$.

The Jacobian is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, and so for each entry $i,j$ of $P( \cdot )$:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}P_{ij}(t_1+t_2)\,dt_1\,dt_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-x}^{x}\dfrac{1}{2}P_{ij}(x)\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}xP_{ij}(x)\,dx$.

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}CP(t_1+t_2)\,dt_1\,dt_2 = C\int_{0}^{\infty}xP(x)\,dx$, assuming both integrals converge.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me which theory you use to derive $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}P_{ij}(t_1+t_2)\,dt_1\,dt_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-x}^{x}\dfrac{1}{2}P_{ij}(x)\,dy\,dx$? I cannot figure out.

Comment: what is the meaning of 'Jocobian' in here?